# mysql return two minimum values with limit

Tags: mysql

I have a table named: workers and a table named: schedule with the following format:

workers:

```
| id | name      | vacationA  | vacationB  | workhistory |
|  1 | Florin    | 2017-05-05 | 2017-05-25 | 2010-01-01  |
|  2 | Andrei    | 2017-06-05 | 2017-06-25 | 2010-01-01  |
|  3 | Alexandra | 2017-07-05 | 2017-07-25 | 2010-01-01  |
|  4 | Emilia    | 2017-08-05 | 2017-08-25 | 2010-01-01  |
|  5 | Nicoleta  | 2017-09-05 | 2017-09-25 | 2010-01-01  |
+----+-----------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

schedule:

```
| day | month | name      | shifts |
+-----+-------+-----------+--------+
|   1 |     6 | Florin    |      0 |
|   1 |     6 | Andrei    |      1 |
|   1 |     6 | Alexandra |      2 |
|   1 |     6 | Emilia    |      3 |
|   1 |     6 | Nicoleta  |      4 |
+-----+-------+-----------+--------+
```

I need to interrogate table "workers" to give me 2 random names, with minimum shifts number, and workers should not be in vacation period. Also work history must be greater than 18 MONTHS.
In this case, the query i need should return Florin and Andrei.

This is what I've got so far, but it doesn't work as supposed:

```
SELECT name
FROM workers
WHERE (CURDATE() NOT BETWEEN vacationA AND vacationB) AND
      workhistory > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)) AND
      name IN (SELECT name FROM schedule ORDER BY shifts LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
```

This query returns 
`1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`.

Thank you!

Comment: `, with minimum shifts number` ... what does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join to `schedule` instead and then use `LIMIT 2`:

```
SELECT w.name
FROM workers w
INNER JOIN schedule s
    ON w.name = s.name
WHERE CURDATE() NOT BETWEEN w.vacationA AND w.vacationB AND
      w.workhistory > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 18 MONTH)
ORDER BY s.shifts
LIMIT 2;
```

I don't understand the random ordering, because you are only returning two worker records, and those records are not chosen randomly, but rather belong to the smallest shift numbers.